# How to Async Job Scedule in EJB Project

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I am writing webservices to run on Jboss-eap-6.2 using EJB and I need to schedule a job inside it with options:
    
    -->Start
    
    -->Pause
    
    -->Resume
    
    -->Stop

N.B: I have Idea about EJB Timer and I know how to work with it but due to Technical problem we don't want to use EJB Timer and Java Timer. 

Is there are other way or third party tools that can be used for resolving my problem?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP 6.2 only implements Java EE 6, which does not include [JSR 236](https://jcp.org/ja/jsr/detail?id=236), which means you are limited to EJB timers or non-EE threading libraries (java.util.Timer, ScheduledExecutorService, or third-party libraries like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)).  For the non-EE threading libraries, you need to be careful with your use of Java EE APIs since they typically do not work well with threads that are not managed by the application server.